# Layout: Display string made in java class

Tags: android, eclipse, string, class, layout

How do I display a string, made in a java class, in my layout activity?
When using "@string/stringexample"  it gives the error of the string being non-existant.

Could you also please give the code made in the java class as I think the code i made doesn't work ( I already deleted it)

Also, the whole thing doesnt start the new layout when pressing a button.

Could you please help me out? Thanks

**Code of main class (without the making of the string):**

```
 package com.barth.appie;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalculate);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Calculated.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}



public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

}
```

**Code of the second class, displaying a new activity:**

```
package com.barth.appie;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Calculated extends MainActivity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculated);

 }
}
```

edit: I want the button to start the new class, which starts the new layout, in which i wanted to display a string, and for some reason the new layout doesnt start on press of the button, and I didnt manage to make a string in the java class and output it in the layout activity.

Comment: what exactly you want to do??

Comment: I wanted the button to start the new class, which starts the new layout, in which i wanted to display a string, and for some reason the new layout doesnt start on press of the button, and I didnt manage to make a string in the java class and output it in the layout activity.

Comment: Based on your explanation best would be for you to start studying Android from the very beginning. Google has excellent material http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html You need to understand how resources work.

Comment: Thanks, but I already experimented with this a bit before, and I'm now copying bits of my old apps in this new one because I forgot some things. The thing is that I already got working buttons and things in my older apps, but in this one I get this error. I just want to play around a bit without making too much effort..

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}
```

Add `addListenerOnButton()` in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       addListenerOnButton();

}
```

You should extend with `Activity` instead of `MainActivity`

```
public class Calculated extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.calculated);
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the error that I must override it, and if I want to remove the override annotation. I got that error earlier and removed it. Do i need to place it at the beginning of the class or something?

Comment: If i extend with "Activity" it totally errors, my main acitivty is called MainActivity so i think that should be OK?

Comment: Thanks for the strings tip, I totally forgot you had to add them

Comment: Organize import, if any import is missing.. Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: The app just errors now when implenting your "Activity" and the code. Also it just still doesnt start a new layout when pressing the button.

Comment: I think im giving up :( Thanks for your help